# set_inst_override_by_type() override fail

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to get a object value from before/after override by factory.
Basically I implement 2 objects and they have constrainted `i_type`.

```
class cfg extends uvm_object;
  rand int unsigned i_type;
 
  `uvm_object_utils_begin(cfg);
  `uvm_field_int (i_type, UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_object_utils_end
 
    constraint i_tpye_c { i_type == 'h88; }
  function new(string name="cfg");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction : new
endclass
 
class c_0 extends cfg;
  `uvm_object_utils(c_0)
  constraint i_type_c { i_type == 2'b11; }
  function new(string name="cfg_0");
    super.new(name);
  endfunction : new
endclass
```

There are 2 problems.

1. When I check the `i_type` value before and after override, they are all `00`. Actually I though that before override I can get a i_type =`88` and after override i_type = `2'b11`.
   How do I correctly get the i_type value?

For your understand I implemented in https://edaplayground.com/x/LpE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the `i_type` variable as an `int` type.  When you constructed the object containing the variable using `create`, it set `i_type` to 0, which is the default value of `int` types.

Since you did nothing else to change the value of the variable, it prints out as 0.

You added constraints for the variable, but they only have effect when you call `randomize` on the object. Therefore, you need to call `randomize`, for example:

```
m_cfg.randomize();
```